# ASP.NET TabContainer and Bootstrap Conflict

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I tried to use the ajaxtoolkit control (tabContainer) in my aspx webpage but i got a problem in the header text display as it's show in the folowing image. i run it under IE too and i got the same problem.
i'm using the latest version of bootstrap and Jquery. Any help ? thanks in advance.
[image: Runing the project under Google Chrome]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your style sheet:

```
.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_tab 
{    
    height:25px !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks anyway. It was due to a CSS conflict between bootstrap and ajaxtoolkit. Finally i droped down ajaxtoolkit and moved on to Jquery UI =)